# Can i use {{sometitle}} as text (without parsing as chunk) in modx evo?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I just got a problem using revolution slider in modx evolution.
My slider have jquery code

```
tabs: {
tmp:'<div class="tp-tab-content">  <span class="tp-tab-date">{{param1}}</span>  <span class="tp-tab-title">{{title}}</span></div><div class="tp-tab-image"></div>'}
```

and modx of course parsing {{param1}} and {{title}} as chunks, but its part of revoslider's jquery.

so after parsign page html code looks like this

```
tabs: {
tmp:'<div class="tp-tab-content">  <span class="tp-tab-date"></span>  <span class="tp-tab-title"></span></div><div class="tp-tab-image"></div>'}
```

and revolution slider shows incorrect

i tried calling revoslider code from html file using snipnet with php funtion **include**, but it also got parsed by modx engine

can i solve this problem without changing revoslider jquery code?

thanks to your ansewers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an EVO expert, but I could suggest several tricks that may help:

- Try to escape the curly braces like `\{\{param1\}\}`
- Try to breake the sequence like `{[*fakeTemplateVar*]{param1}[*fakeTemplateVar*]}`*
- Try an empty TV like `[*fakeTemplateVar*:ifempty={{param1}}]`

*`fakeTemplateVar` will finally evaluate to an empty place in the template.

Comment: @icyberbot Glad to hear! Feel free to mark it as an answer or upvote if it was helpful.